# R - Reorder NULL columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the next question.
If I have the following data frame db and I want to rearrange the columns so that they the NULL columns stay at the ends (as in db2).
How can I do it dynamically?
Thank you

```
db<-data.frame(N=c(2,4,6,8),
               a=c(1,1,1,1),
               b=c(1,1,1,1),
               c=c(NA,1,1,1),
               d=c(NA,1,1,1),
               e=c(NA,NA,1,1),
               f=c(NA,NA,1,1),
               g=c(NA,NA,NA,1),
               h=c(NA,NA,NA,1))

db2<-data.frame(N=c(2,4,6,8),
                a=c(NA,NA,NA,1),
                b=c(NA,NA,1,1),
                c=c(NA,1,1,1),
                d=c(1,1,1,1),
                e=c(1,1,1,1),
                f=c(NA,1,1,1),
                g=c(NA,NA,1,1),
                h=c(NA,NA,NA,1))

  N  a  b  c d e  f  g  h
1 2 NA NA NA 1 1 NA NA NA
2 4 NA NA  1 1 1  1 NA NA
3 6 NA  1  1 1 1  1  1 NA
4 8  1  1  1 1 1  1  1  1
```

Comment: Do you always have even number of NAs per row?

Comment: Yeah, always like that. With even and null cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of NAs per row are always even, then loop through the rows, rearrange the NA by appending half the NAs at the start and end

```
db[-1] <- t(apply(db[-1], 1, function(x) {
     i1 <- is.na(x)
    if(sum(i1) > 0) setNames(c(rep(NA,sum(i1)/2), x[!i1], 
       rep(NA, sum(i1)/2)), names(x)) else x}))
db
#  N  a  b  c d e  f  g  h
#1 2 NA NA NA 1 1 NA NA NA
#2 4 NA NA  1 1 1  1 NA NA
#3 6 NA  1  1 1 1  1  1 NA
#4 8  1  1  1 1 1  1  1  1
```